# ArangoDB: (1 Graph with several Edge Definition) Vs (1 Edge Definition per Graph)

Tags: graph-databases, arangodb, nosql

I was wondering if there is any advantage to having several edges definition in one single graph Vs having several graphs each one with a single edge definition.

Thanks for you help,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are different reasons for using multiple edge definitions instead of only one:

1. To show differences in content: You may want to have different edge collections for `bought` and `watched`. This is also possible by using a label however and comes down to personal preference.
2. Edge definitions allow you to restrict the collections on the `in` and on the `out` side of the edges. So you can for example say that your `bought` transitions always start in a document for the `people` collection and go to the `product` collection. You would otherwise need to do that inside of your application.

Comment: Thanks, If i understand correctly it seems to be just a matter of preference. Is there any computational/memory-usage advantage to the single graph approach?

Comment: Computational/Memory-wise it should be equivalent. Point 2 is however a functional difference.